# Difference between UnittWebSocketClient library and SocketRocket. Which one is efficient to use?

Tags: websocket, socketrocket

Difference between `UnittWebSocketClient` library and `SocketRocket`. Which one is efficient to use to implement `WebSockets` in iOS Apps?

Answer (score 1):

`SocketRocket` seems to me more maintained to me. `UnittWebSocketClient` has not been updated since Dezember 2012. I started to use `SocketRocket` in one of my last projects.

Comment: do u know how to integrate it in OS x app. I'm bit confused for it.

Comment: Yes, I was able to integrate it in my OS X app and it works fine.